# Why is the screen freezing on me?

Tags: 22.04, freeze, 23.04

Recently, my 22.04 installation started freezing in a particular way:

1. screen frozen;
2. keyboard input seemingly not doing anything;
3. **BUT** computer still working.

I know that **3** is true because I have been on Zoom calls when it froze; the call keeps going, I can hear people talking, but, as I said, the screen is frozen and nothing I do with the keyboard (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>) does anything.

I upgraded to 23.04 but the problem has continued.

I have inspected the system log before the freezes but I cannot work out from those what is going on.

**ANSWERS TO QUESTIONS:**

1. I have not changed the default graphics drivers.
2. My kernel is 6.2.xxx.

**UPDATE:**

I think that it has something to do with Firefox. I have inserted a *new* log below (and have removed the old ones due to word count) where it happened *immediately* after opening Firefox.

```
Oct 11 10:20:14 thinkpad-E580 systemd[3585]: Started app-gnome-firefox-7954.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell.
Oct 11 10:20:15 thinkpad-E580 systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 11 10:20:15 thinkpad-E580 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=8c:16:45:27:f1:31:98:da:c4:a8:9a:a6:08:00 SRC=18.67.91.56 DST=192.168.1.107 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=249 ID=56662 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=51182 WINDOW=131 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Oct 11 10:20:15 thinkpad-E580 firefox.desktop[7954]: ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
Oct 11 10:20:15 thinkpad-E580 firefox.desktop[7954]: ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
Oct 11 10:20:16 thinkpad-E580 dbus-daemon[3006]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.service' requested by ':1.92' (uid=1000 pid=7954 comm="/usr/local/bin/firefox" label="unconfined")
Oct 11 10:20:16 thinkpad-E580 systemd[1]: Starting systemd-timedated.service - Time & Date Service...
Oct 11 10:20:16 thinkpad-E580 dbus-daemon[3006]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
Oct 11 10:20:16 thinkpad-E580 systemd[1]: Started systemd-timedated.service - Time & Date Service.
Oct 11 10:20:16 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:16 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:16 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:16 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:16 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:16 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:16 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Successfully made thread 8192 of process 7954 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Oct 11 10:20:16 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:17 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:17 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:17 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:17 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:17 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:17 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:17 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:17 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:19 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:19 thinkpad-E580 rtkit-daemon[3934]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Oct 11 10:20:35 thinkpad-E580 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=8c:16:45:27:f1:31:98:da:c4:a8:9a:a6:08:00 SRC=142.250.71.67 DST=192.168.1.107 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=122 ID=6468 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=46552 WINDOW=261 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Oct 11 10:20:46 thinkpad-E580 systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 11 10:20:46 thinkpad-E580 systemd-logind[3061]: Power key pressed short.
Oct 11 10:20:48 thinkpad-E580 systemd-logind[3061]: Power key pressed short.
Oct 11 10:20:51 thinkpad-E580 systemd-logind[3061]: Power key pressed short.
Oct 11 10:21:00 thinkpad-E580 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=8c:16:45:27:f1:31:98:da:c4:a8:9a:a6:08:00 SRC=34.117.65.55 DST=192.168.1.107 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=122 ID=26377 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=52442 WINDOW=285 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Oct 11 10:21:01 thinkpad-E580 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=8c:16:45:27:f1:31:98:da:c4:a8:9a:a6:08:00 SRC=34.117.65.55 DST=192.168.1.107 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=122 ID=26378 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=52442 WINDOW=285 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Oct 11 10:21:01 thinkpad-E580 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=8c:16:45:27:f1:31:98:da:c4:a8:9a:a6:08:00 SRC=34.117.65.55 DST=192.168.1.107 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=122 ID=26379 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=52442 WINDOW=285 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Oct 11 10:21:01 thinkpad-E580 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=8c:16:45:27:f1:31:98:da:c4:a8:9a:a6:08:00 SRC=34.117.65.55 DST=192.168.1.107 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=122 ID=26380 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=52442 WINDOW=285 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Oct 11 10:21:02 thinkpad-E580 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=8c:16:45:27:f1:31:98:da:c4:a8:9a:a6:08:00 SRC=34.117.65.55 DST=192.168.1.107 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=122 ID=26381 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=52442 WINDOW=285 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Oct 11 10:21:03 thinkpad-E580 systemd-logind[3061]: Power key pressed short.
Oct 11 10:21:04 thinkpad-E580 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=8c:16:45:27:f1:31:98:da:c4:a8:9a:a6:08:00 SRC=142.250.71.67 DST=192.168.1.107 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=122 ID=6469 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=46552 WINDOW=261 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Oct 11 10:21:04 thinkpad-E580 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=8c:16:45:27:f1:31:98:da:c4:a8:9a:a6:08:00 SRC=34.117.65.55 DST=192.168.1.107 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=122 ID=26382 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=52442 WINDOW=285 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Oct 11 10:21:08 thinkpad-E580 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=8c:16:45:27:f1:31:98:da:c4:a8:9a:a6:08:00 SRC=34.117.65.55 DST=192.168.1.107 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=122 ID=26383 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=52442 WINDOW=285 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Oct 11 10:21:10 thinkpad-E580 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:98:da:c4:a8:9a:a6:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Oct 11 10:21:21 thinkpad-E580 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=8c:16:45:27:f1:31:98:da:c4:a8:9a:a6:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.25 DST=192.168.1.107 LEN=113 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=37646 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=42052 WINDOW=63 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Oct 11 10:21:22 thinkpad-E580 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=8c:16:45:27:f1:31:98:da:c4:a8:9a:a6:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.25 DST=192.168.1.107 LEN=113 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=37647 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=42052 WINDOW=63 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Oct 11 10:21:26 thinkpad-E580 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=8c:16:45:27:f1:31:98:da:c4:a8:9a:a6:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.25 DST=192.168.1.107 LEN=113 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=37650 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=42052 WINDOW=63 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Oct 11 10:21:26 thinkpad-E580 systemd-logind[3061]: Power key pressed short.
```

Comment: Interesting, I just had this happen as well, but on Fedora 38. I was watching a video on YouTube, and then the screen froze and keyboard did not work anymore (which means I could not get out of it via REISUB and had to force a power-off via the power button). The journals did not have anything helpful, but Nautilus was spamming the “Attempted to add a non-existent file to the view” message multiple times a second and hundreds of lines in total. You also have that row in your log, so I wonder if it is related somehow? Or the fact we both had video playback active in the browser? 

Comment: I found out what my problem is. There is an AMD graphics bug in Linux 6.5 which can freeze the whole system when doing really mundane things like video playback, games, or just using Google Maps: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/2830. This bug is fixed in Linux 6.5.6.

Comment: @Person you may want to write out a full answer, including how you installed a newer kernel or what else you did.

Comment: @user68186 OP’s hardware has Intel graphics, so the bug I mentioned is not relevant to them.

Answer (score 0):

The logs unfortunately don't give any clear indicator as to the source of the problem.

This problem can often be caused by unstable graphics drivers. Messing with graphics drivers can brick your OS (so make a backup first!), but you can try going to the "additional drivers" app in Ubuntu and try alternate drivers. If those don't work, you could also install drivers directly from the manufacturer if they offer any.

This problem can also be caused by bad memory (RAM), but if that were happening I wouldn't expect zoom etc to keep working. You can use a tool like memtest86+ to test this.